# SpringBoot v2.7.0 - Select-Query without transactional-annotation => No transactional EntityManager available | now with github-example

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently working on an older Spring project (not Spring Boot). This uses the spring-boot-dependencies as the parent BOM. A migration to SpringBoot is planned for the near future. We are currently still using the dependencies from version 2.6.7. I would now like to upgrade to 2.7.0.

I have problems with my own queries in a JPA repository. The query is a JPQL query that only executes a select:
`@Query("select x from y where y.date = (select max(tmp.date) from y tmp where y.thingId = tmp.thingId)")`

When running the query, "No transactional EntityManager available" is thrown. If I annotate the repository or method with a Transactional-annotation, the query runs. However, I am surprised that this is now necessary? Previously, the query could be executed without Transactional annotation. Has there been a change here? I don´t find any information in the release note.

---

Edit: i have create a abstract github-project with the issue: https://github.com/helo-trix/72520519

Comment: did you add another database connetion?

Comment: I have the same issue when I migrated to spring boot 2.7.0 . I also have multiple datasource in my project . So ... what is the link between multiple DS, spring boot 2.7.0 and entity manager ? What happened in Spring Boot 2.7.0 ? My code was working with 2.6.7 . Regards

Comment: I have only one DS. Watch my edit for a github-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that has been fixed here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/pull/2542

upgrading to springboot 2.7.2 will fix your problem